# SQL: Split or sum up duration into daily intervals

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table `Usage(user_id, start_date_time, end_date_time)` indicating user's usage of a resource. It can have several entries for the same calendar day when the resource was used on & off, other entries can be spanning several days.

I want to produce a list with each user's daily use of the resource, summing up short entries and splitting long ones. The result should be like `DailyUsage(user_id, usage_date, total_usage)`

Days when a resource was not used at all may be not present or present with zero total, whichever is easier.

Example:

```
Usage
(1, 2021-05-18 13:00:00, 2021-05-18 14:00:00)
(1, 2021-05-18 17:00:00, 2021-05-18 18:00:00)
(1, 2021-05-21 15:00:00, 2021-05-23 08:00:00)

DailyUsage
(1, 2021-05-18, 2)
(1, 2021-05-21, 9)
(1, 2021-05-22, 24)
(1, 2021-05-23, 8)
```

Comment: A calendar table would be a big help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is there such thing, or should I create it myself?

Comment: . . I don't think one is built into Redshift.  Hey, is Amazon listening?

Comment: how would you solve this if I had one? @GordonLinoff